# Determine sample size without knowing standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, sample-size

I want to calculate the required sample size for a call centre with a finite population.

The survey will collect data on many variables. The objective is to gain data about a range of psychological aspects as well as durations, agent performance, call resolution etc. Therefore I cannot choose a sample size and calculate the standard deviation with a pilot, because I wouldn't know what to base the deviation on.

I have read that an industry standard deviation can be used, however I have no such info.

So if I cannot calculate it using a pilot, do not know the industry st.d should I guess the standard deviation in order to calculate the sample size? If so, how can I make an educated guess?

Could I instead calculate the sample size using proportions? as described in (http://www.polarismr.com/research-lifeline/sample-size-calculator/)

In this link (http://www.surveysystem.com/sample-size-formula.htm) there is a formula for calculating it ignoring the standard deviation. Is this recommendable?

I am very grateful for replies. Please keep in mind that I am new to statistics and I might have overseen some important info above.

Comment: I don't follow this. One point to the pilot is to obtain preliminary information such as useful estimates of population variances, which can then be used to design a full study. The pilot is intentionally made small so that no resources are wasted in collecting unnecessary information. What prevents you from conducting such a pilot study, then?

Comment: The questionnaire consists of many variables. If I am to do a pilot and calculate the standard deviation, which variable should I choose? The outcome of the questionnaire will show many different deviations depending on which variables I select.